# Margin-left on table based on screen width, with scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a sticky table column with employee names on the left side of my screen. And a large table with a scrollbar next to it.

The idea is when im scroling to the right to see the content of the large table that my sticky table column with names pushes the table to the right.

In that way I've got a nice overview of the names on the left side of the screen, and it's not overlapping my table.

Can't seem to get it to work properly, does anybody have some suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve effect like *Excel fixed column*:

Do like this:

```
.table-wrapper { 
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:visible;
    width:250px;
    margin-left: 120px;
}

td, th {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    width: 100px;
}

th:first-child {
    position: fixed;
    left: 5px
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJqPf/2486/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-2">Left side</div>
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <th>TH1</th>
          <th>TH2</th>
          <th>TH3</th>
          <th>TH4</th>
          <th>TH5</th>
          <th>TH6</th>
          <th>TH7</th>
          <th>TH8</th>
          <th>TH9</th>
          <th>TH10</th>
          <th>TH11</th>
          <th>TH12</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <td>TD1</td>
          <td>TD2</td>
          <td>TD3</td>
          <td>TD4</td>
          <td>TD5</td>
          <td>TD6</td>
          <td>TD7</td>
          <td>TD8</td>
          <td>TD9</td>
          <td>TD10</td>
          <td>TD11</td>
          <td>TD12</td>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <th>TH1</th>
          <th>TH2</th>
          <th>TH3</th>
          <th>TH4</th>
          <th>TH5</th>
          <th>TH6</th>
          <th>TH7</th>
          <th>TH8</th>
          <th>TH9</th>
          <th>TH10</th>
          <th>TH11</th>
          <th>TH12</th>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This example is in version 3, but you can use the new one (v4).